# .endswith missing file extention in a loop

Tags: python

I'm loading extentions from a config file like so;

```
search_ext = tuple((config.get("Miscellaneous", "media") + config.get("Miscellaneous", "meta") + config.get("Miscellaneous", "other")).split('|'))
```

In the config file extentions are listed like so;

> media = .mkv|.avi|.divx|.xvid|.mov|.wmv|.mp4|.mpg|.mpeg|.vob|.iso
>
> meta = .nfo|.sub|.srt|.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.txt
>
> other = .exe|.pdf

Then looping through a file list using os.walk, searching with .endswith

```
if fileName.endswith(search_ext):
```

But it seems to always miss the last extention, eg in this case it would be .pdf. Easily circumvented with adding a bogus extention like .unknown or so. But why is this? Has it anything to do with my tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip space around the configuration value. (This may not be the issue, according to `config`)

The last element of `media` and the first element of `meta` are concatenated without separator. (Same for `meta`,`other`)

```
search_ext = (
     config.get("Miscellaneous", "media").strip() + '|' +
     config.get("Miscellaneous", "meta").strip() + '|' +
     config.get("Miscellaneous", "other").strip()
).split('|')
```